# POST a file as a binary stream to server using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a doubt, I have tried searching on the web generally, but I do not find the answer i want.
from the local system, I have uploaded a file using html input type=file attribute.
now i would like to make this file as a binary stream using javascript and then do a POST of this stream to the server.
Does anyone have an idea or an example code for me to understand how it works?

For ex:
i have

```
<input type="file" id="myFile">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Upload</button>
<script>
function myFunction() 

    {
    var x = document.getElementById("myFile"); 
    //convert x to a IOstream*
    //do a HTTP POST request to server and also write the file as stream like request.getstream
    }

</script>
```

Is this possible with only JS? At the moment I am only focusing on uplaoding media files like images.
it has to be uploaded as a IOstream because that is the only format accepted by server.
Also, it has to work with Safari!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmmmm... place your `<input>` inside a `<form method="post">` and `submit()` it?

Comment: Just use `FormData`.

Answer (score 2):

### FileReader methods support

`FileReader.readAsBinaryString(`) **is deprecated. Don't use it!** It's no longer in the [W3C File API working draft:](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader)

```
void abort();
void readAsArrayBuffer(Blob blob);
void readAsText(Blob blob, optional DOMString encoding);
void readAsDataURL(Blob blob);
```

NB: Note that `File` is a kind of extended `Blob` structure.

Mozilla still implements `readAsBinaryString()` and describe it in [MDN FileApi documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader):

```
void abort();
void readAsArrayBuffer(in Blob blob); Requires Gecko 7.0
void readAsBinaryString(in Blob blob);
void readAsDataURL(in Blob file);
void readAsText(in Blob blob, [optional] in DOMString encoding);
```

The reason behind `readAsBinaryString()` deprecation is in y opinion the following: The standard for Javascript strings are `DOMString` which only accept UTF-8 characters, NOT random binary data. So don't use readAsBinaryString(), that's not safe and ECMAScript-compliant at all.

We know that **Javascript strings are not supposed to store binary data** but Mozilla in some sort can. That's dangerous in my opinion. `Blob` and `typed arrays` (`ArrayBuffer` and the not-yet-implemented but not necessary `StringView`) were invented for one purpose: allow the use of pure binary data, without UTF-8 strings restrictions.

### XMLHttpRequest upload support

[XMLHttpRequest.send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest#send%28%29) has the following invocations options:

```
void send();
void send(ArrayBuffer data);
void send(Blob data);
void send(Document data);
void send(DOMString? data);
void send(FormData data);
```

[XMLHttpRequest.sendAsBinary()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest#sendAsBinary%28%29) has the following invocations options:

```
void sendAsBinary(   in DOMString body );
```

sendAsBinary() is NOT a standard and may not be supported in Chrome.

### Solutions

---

So you have several options:

1. `send()` the `FileReader.result` of `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer ( fileObject )`. It is more complicated to manipulate (you'll have to make a separate send() for it) but it's the RECOMMENDED APPROACH.
2. `send()` the `FileReader.result` of `FileReader.readAsDataURL( fileObject )`. It generates useless overhead and compression latency, requires a decompression step on the server-side BUT it's easy to manipulate as a string in Javascript.
3. Being non-standard and `sendAsBinary()` the `FileReader.result` of `FileReader.readAsBinaryString( fileObject  )`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest#send%28%29) states that:

> The best way to send binary content (like in files upload) is using
>   ArrayBuffers or Blobs in conjuncton with the send() method. However,
>   if you want to send a stringifiable raw data, use the sendAsBinary()
>   method instead, or the StringView (Non native) typed arrays
>   superclass.

Comment: If i were to upload only media files (because i will be using the webapp on ipad and thr an applet is not possible) , so the only alternative is to do a POST as sourcestream to the server. In this scenario which would be the simplest way to proceed using javascript  that also helps when using safari browser